# ¿Cómo retirar mi voto para cerrar?

Tags: soporte

Voté para cerrar [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/764/292) que me parecía demasiado amplia, pero el OP enseguida añadió detalles que mejoraban la pregunta y la hacían más específica, por lo que, post-edits, mi voto de cierre ya no es relevante.

Si hago click en la opción *cerrar* me indica que ya he votado por cerrar, y yo esperaba que me dejase **retractar o retirar mi voto de cierre**. Estoy casi convencido de haberlo hecho así en otros *Stacks*. No sé si esta funcionalidad todavía no está activa en esta beta, si es un problema de privilegios o u bug.

¿Cómo puedo retractar mi voto de cierre para una pregunta?

---

Desde la lista de preguntas en la página de inicio hago click en "cerrar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y veo la siguiente ventana (sin botón para retractar el voto)

[image: votar para cerrar]

Probado en Chrome Version 47.0.2526.80 (64-bit) y OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 (y he de añadir que con los mismos medios y de la misma manera no he tenido problemas en otros *stacks*)

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y a mí sí me funciona la "retractación" del voto de cierre.

Comment: También acabo de probarlo y me funcionó. Vuelve a intentarlo.

Comment: Gracias a ambos. He añadido una imagen de lo que veo. Al contrario de lo que señala la [respuesta de @Rubén](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/234/292) no veo el botón para retirar el voto de cierre. Si esa funcionalidad no es dependiente de privilegios/reputación entonces debe ser bug. Debería añadir el tag correcpondiente?

Comment: Sí, sería bueno añadir [bug] así como la versión de navegador que utilizas, así como si utilizas algún tipo de plugin.

Comment: Además, agregar los pasos los pasos seguidos, es decir, indica si accediste desde la lista de preguntas en la página de inicio o desde la cola de revisión, ...

Answer (score 6):

Para retirar un voto de cierre

1. Hacer clic en cerrar (n)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Hacer clic en "Retirar el voto de cierre"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]