# ¿Cómo voto para NO cerrar?

Tags: soporte

Veo una pregunta que actualmente no está cerrada y está propuesta para cerrar y con 3 votos. Le faltan 2 para ser cerrada.

Pero yo pienso que no habría que cerrarla. ¿Puedo votar para que NO se cierre? Y si puedo, ¿cómo?

No estoy preguntando [¿Cómo retirar mi voto para cerrar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/c%C3%B3mo-retirar-mi-voto-para-cerrar)
Nunca he llegado a votar para cerrar esa pregunta.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Esta : http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2461/cu%C3%A1les-son-los-da%C3%B1os-que-pueden-ser-causados-por-el-mal-uso-de-las-herramientas . En el sitio en inglés la rechazarían, pero yo creo que debieramos aceptarla porque no hay ni va a haber otros sitios alternativos en español como programmers o security en inglés.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Una vez que una pregunta recibe un voto o una recomendación de cierre la misma se va para la fila de análisis. Allá puedes votar para `Dejar abierta` o para `Cerrarla`. Si han muchos votos para dejarla abierta en la fila una hora ella sale de allá, pero los votos de cierre aún poden ser dados directamente en la pregunta.

Entonces, lo mejor que puedes hacer mientras no se cierre és votar en la fila para mantenerla abierta, para que salga de allá lo más rápido posible y no llame más atención para si. Pero una vez cerrada nada impede que la misma sea reaberta con la misma cantidad de votos de cierre: cinco.

La pregunta en cuestión ya ha salido de la fila gracias al voto de moderador, mire: [Revisar|Votos de cierre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/2070)

> Revisión completada hace 6 horas

Answer (score 5):

Hoy por hoy no parece existir esa funcionalidad en Stack Overflow, lo más parecido es votar para reapertura una vez que la pregunta ya ha sido cerrada. Siempre puedes dejar un comentario en la pregunta explicando por qué crees que no debería ser cerrada.

Answer (score 2):

Si bien no se puede votar para NO cerrar, lo mejor, en mi opinión, es tratar de pedirle al dueño de la pregunta mediante comentarios que trate de mejorar la pregunta o editando vos mismo y votar para reabrir.

Los comentarios ayudan mucho a entenderse entre todos, hay que tenerlos en cuenta.

Answer (score -6):

Yo voté para [cerrarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2461/cu%C3%A1les-son-los-da%C3%B1os-que-pueden-ser-causados-por-el-mal-uso-de-las-herramientas) porque existen otros sitios donde puedes preguntar eso. ¿En inglés? Sí, en inglés, exactamente el mismo idioma en el que está la documentación de la pregunta en cuestión y que el autor dice que estaba leyendo. Eso me da a entender claramente que el autor habla inglés con el nivel suficiente para poder preguntar en el sitio correcto.

He visto el [perfil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2851440/andr%C3%A9s-mu%C3%B1oz) de SO del autor y ya ha preguntado antes en el sitio en inglés, así que no creo que lo pregunte acá porque tenga una barrera con el idioma.

Ahora, en sí la pregunta sería cerrada en SO en segundos, acá también debería si consideramos todo lo que he dicho.

Yo en su lugar si quisiera la opinión de la comunidad en una pregunta de ese estilo, lo hubiera preguntado en el chat.

Comment: Eso no responde la pregunta. El autor no quiere la opinión de la comunidad se la pregunta debe o no ser cerrada, el quiere saber como se vota para que no se cierre una determinada pregunta, tanto que el tampouco he puesto el enlace en la pregunta, fuera más una cuestión de curiosidad que surgió después en los comentarios.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias.